# Rails 4.1.6 inserting not saving in database from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is my controller code

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def new
    DashboardUser.create(
      :USER_NAME => params[:user_name],
      :PASSWORD => params[:password],
      :LAST_NAME => params[:last_name],
      :FIRST_NAME => params[:first_name],
      :MIDDLE_NAME => params[:middle_name],
      :PHONE => params[:phone]
     )
  end
  private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
  end
end
```

below is my model code

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "dashboard_user"
end
```

below is my html.erb code

```
<%= form_tag("/admin/user_creation", :method=>"post") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:user_name) %>
    <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:last_name) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:first_name) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:middle_name) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:phone) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Add User", :class=>"btn") %>
    <% end %>
```

so what happens is that when i click add user the parameters are not saved into the database by the controller.

Is there anything i could do to pass the values to the database ?

i am new to rails please help thanks :D

routes.rb code

```
       Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end
  resources :admin, :only => [:show, :new, :user_creation]
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'admin#user_creation'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end


end
```

this is my routes .rb code 
i am trying to get to the same page after submitting the form

**error trace**

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for AdminController):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:131:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/vadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/vadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/vadmin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Try dashboard_params[:user_name] in stead of params[:user_name] and so on..

Comment: No route matches [POST] "/admin/user_creation"

Rails.root: /home/vadmin/Ruby/Dashboard/Dashboard getting this error

Comment: What is in your routes?  You should really also have a dashboard user controller with all of the operations in

Comment: routes.rb code added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your whole process is wrong, you are submitting form to new action and its a `get` method. Do this

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
  end

  def user_creation
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_params)
    @dashboard_user.save!
  end


private
  def dashboard_params
    params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
  end
end
```

In your view, it should be `admin/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @dashboard_user, url: "/admin/user_creation", method: "post" do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:user_name) %>
    <%= f.password_field(:password) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:last_name) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:first_name) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:middle_name) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:phone) %>
    <%= f.submit "Add User", :class=>"btn" %>
<% end %>
```

and in your routes `user_creation` should be `post` action

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :admin do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end

  root 'admin#new'
end
```

Comment: i get this param is missing or the value is empty: dashboard_user
 when i use the above controller code

Comment: change everything, view, routes and all

Comment: The action 'show' could not be found for AdminController

Comment: have you changed that action to `post` in routes, check routes in my answer

Comment: yes bro i have changed that to post 'user_creation', on: :collection

Comment: check in console if the record is getting saved in the database or not

Comment: it says Started GET "/admin/user_creation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 16:23:19 +0530

Comment: param is missing or the value is empty: dashboard_user
params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)

Comment: I have edited the form_for tag, added `method: "post"`

Comment: still getting the same issue :\

Comment: resources :admin, :only => [:show, :new, :create] will this type of routes will work?

Comment: I have edited the answer, change `root 'admin#user_creation'` to `root 'admin#new'`

Comment: this is redirecting to show.html.erb this code -->resources :admin do
    post 'user_creation', on: :collection
  end

Comment: No, change your root as I mentioned and check

Comment: Started GET "/admin/user_creation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-06 18:34:12 +0530
Processing by AdminController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"user_creation"}
  Rendered admin/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 102.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: i changed and then this

Answer (score -1):

you need to use your resource to create your record. So, here is something you can change.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
    DashboardUser.create(dashboard_params)
  end
  private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name , :phone)
  end
end


<%= form_for(@dashboard_user, url: some_path, :method=>"post") do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field(:user_name) %>
    <%= f.text_field(:middle_name) %>
    <%= f.submit("Add User", :class=>"btn") %>
<% end %>
```

Should be something like that...does this make more sense to you?

Comment: Some_path here will be my default path?

Comment: like admin/user_Creation?

Comment: getting first argument cannot be nil or empty when i put this <%= form_for(@dashboard_user, url: 'admin/user_creation', :method=>"post") do |f| %>